# What will be the output of the following program? What are the deference between 5.3f and 5.3

Tags: java

What will be the output of the following program? What is the difference between 5.3f and 5.3?

```
public class DemoOnFloat      
{       
    public static void main(String[] args)      
    {    
        float fl = 5.3f;  
        if (fl == 5.3)  
            System.out.println("Both are equal");  
        else  
            System.out.println("Both are not equal");  
    }  
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier for you to just try running this code yourself?  The `f` in `5.3f` just is short for `float`, and tells Java that you are definition a float literal.

Comment: A good way to tell what the output of a program is, is to run it.

Comment: Executing the program will answer your question. Then, if you do not understand the result of the program or if it does not produce the output you expected, you can edit your post to ask a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you write just 5.3 in your source code, Java assumes it as 64 bit Double. That means Java's default data type for floating point numbers is Double. If you want to tell the JVM that this should be a 32 bit float value, you have to explicitly put 'f' after the value.

Therefore in you question, inside the if() condition, you are comparing a float value and a double value. you will get 'both are not equal' as the output.

Additional Note:
Similarly, Java identifies non-decimal numbers as 32 bit Integers by default. If you want to tell the JVM that this should be a 64 bit Long value, you have to explicitly put 'L' after the value.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I feel this misses the point.  Although `(5.3f == 5.3)` is false, `(3.5f == 3.5)` is true.  But you claim that the reason that the first expression comes out false is because you're comparing a `float` to a `double`.  That's not really true.